# Is there way to get first row in PostgreSQL of my table for every different type on project, task or subtask

Tags: postgresql

In my table I have changes that have been made on my web app. Now I need to fetch these changes for every user when he logs in so he can already know where to go. Since last time he was logged there can be many changes and every change is not important anymore. I need to get last change for every project, task or subtask for every different type. In status I have information whether it is complete...

I have already tried to get all changes and then sort it in script on specific page. Problem is that I have to check for every task, subtask and sort out the rest and I'm sure there is way that I can sort those out already in SQL query.

So far I'm using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM changes
WHERE "for" = 1
ORDER BY id_project, id_task, id_subtask, type, date DESC;
```

I would like to get only the rows that are marked in my result of the query:

[image: result picture]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need points to unlock features, generally, because you're not really supposed to need them--in this case, [you should post the code you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) rather than a photo of it, so that others can better understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the fastest way to get results like this in PostgreSQL is to use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_project, id_task, id_subtask, type)
       *
FROM changes
WHERE "for" = 1
ORDER BY id_project, id_task, id_subtask, type, date DESC;
```

This won't make the query faster though. To speed it up, you need an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON changes (for, id_project, id_task, id_subtask, type, date);
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for the correction; I have fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`SELECT DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

Construct your query as you have with an appropriate `ORDER BY`. Then you change `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT ON (col[, ...])`. This will select the first row for each "segment" based on the cols you specify in `ON (...)`. Typically you'll have the same columns as in your `ORDER BY` clause.

In your case I think this should be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_project, id_task, id_subtask, type, date) *
FROM changes
WHERE "for" = 1
ORDER BY id_project, id_task, id_subtask, type, date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, i already accepted the other answer because it was first. The answers are both the same. I removed date from DISTINCT ON to get my wanted result.